# scatter plot of different color in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

How to scatter plot the following:

```
  var1  var2
1  10  2
2  20  4
3  30  8
4  40  16
5  80  32
```

I need to color var1 and var2 with difft colors. x-axis should range from 1 to 5. How can I add a line showing trend of the data?

Comment: It's really not very clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but assuming your data is in df, it sounds like you want something like this to get started:

```
plot(1:5, df$var1, pch=19, col="blue", ylim=c(0,80))
points(1:5, df$var2, pch=19, col="red")
```

As for the trend of the data, what do you mean? A trend for each line? Or do you actually want to plot var1 against var2 (I have assumed you *don't* want that otherwise there would be no point having two colours).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Additionally I also need to draw a regression line that will show the trend of the plotted data points.

Comment: @seancarmody, you can actually drop the `1:5` in this example. Also, to make your answer more generalizable, instead of specifying the `ylim`, you can use something like `ylim=c(0,max(sapply(temp, max))`. That solution is not useful in this simple example, but useful if you have lots of columns and you want to figure out what axis limits would accommodate all the data.

Comment: @learner, to get you started: `abline(lm(df$var1 ~ c(1:5)))` after you have followed @seancarmody's solution. I'll let you figure out different colors, line-types, line weights, and so on....

Comment: @mrdwab,  I need to find if var1 is functionally same or different. In the example data above, they are different as one is polynomial and another is exponential. Which statistical technique can give me this info?